# Replace popup windows with iframes

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, iframe, window

I'm developing a newer web application that sometimes needs to load parts of a legacy application (via CGI) in order to complete various legacy operations. Whenever that needs to happen, I just populate the legacy document into a temporary iframe until the user completed whatever it was needed for. *(BTW, bear in mind the newer app must not allow popups, multiple windows/tabs, etc.)*

But, sometimes, the iframe's legacy document wants to use a popup window. So, I've devised a way to override the legacy's `window.open()` command with a type of modal dialog containing another iframe. This works great....

But my problems arise whenever the popup's form-based document *(now loaded in the modal dialog's iframe)* tries to manage its state. Upon initial load, its form auto-submits to get the latest DB data... after CGI responds with a new document, the user can make a selection. Upon selection, the form once again submits to CGI, which responds with a small JavaScript that injects their selection data to the `opener` window.

My first issue was with the reference to `opener`, since there's effectively not one anymore (as far as the legacy code is concerned). I've kind-of solved that by defining my modal iframe's `contentWindow.opener` to be my legacy document's iframe's window (the first iframe I mentioned).

HOWEVER, when the modal document's form submits, STATE GETS LOST and my `opener` definition is reset to `null`. Therefore, when the user makes their selection in the modal's iframe, the legacy code cannot return any value through the `opener` reference.

So, my question is complicated, but basically...
Is there a way to save a window.opener reference such that it doesn't get lost whenever that window updates? I know JavaScript/DOM is kind of "pass by reference" but I'm worried I'm over-engineering at this point or something.

Any ideas? Tips?
Anyone do anything similar?

Comment: iframes have an `onload` event. Did you try re-injecting the fake opener object at this point?

Comment: @DarkFalcon, that's exactly what I was hoping for... someone to help me see the forest from the trees. I'd completely overlooked the possibility of listening on the `iframe` and was instead focusing on `iframe.contentWindow`... a quick console test suggests it might work ~ or at least help me move on a bit further. I thank you, in advance, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did...
Essentially, I subscribed an `onload` handler that sets `opener` whenever that event fires (with each form submission).

```
myiframe.onload = function(){ 
    myiframe.contentWindow.opener = objWindow_mySavedOpenerReference;
    };
```

Now, each time the state changes, the iframe handles resetting the opener reference in the iframe's window... with that set, any logic that depends on an `opener` reference will now work. --Thanks to @DarkFalcon for help.